# No encuentro el error

Tags: java

Estoy intentando hacer un programa que mediante condiciones entradas por teclado, me genere una serie de números, el programa sería mas o menos así:

Si el usuario ingresa un numero entre 0 y 9 lo agrega a la lista, si el usuario ingresa "D" borra el último dígito de la lista, si el usuario ingresa "C" y un número, borra los últimos elementos de la lista de acuerdo al número que ingresó, si ingresa "B" y un número, borra el dígito que esté en la posición que indica el número ingresado de derecha a izquierda, si ingresa "M" muestra la serie de números hasta el momento, el programa finaliza si el usuario ingresa "F".

El problema es que tengo el código pero no imprime lo que debería y no encuentro el error. Como ejemplo ingreso:

9
8
7
6
5
D
B 2
M
4
3
2
1
C 3
B 4
M
F
y me tendría que devolver dos lineas, una con 986 y otra con 864.

¡No sean tan duros con migo, soy nuevo en programación!

```
    import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList<Integer> lista = new LinkedList<>();
        Iterator<Integer> iterador;
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

        int x, y, i, m;

        String n;

        while (true) {

            n = entrada.next();

            if (n.equals("D")) {
                if (lista.size() != 0) {
                    lista.removeLast();
                }
            } else if (n.equals("C")) {
                y = entrada.nextInt();
                if (y <= lista.size()) {
                    for (i = lista.size() - 1; i == y; i--) {
                        lista.removeLast();
                    }
                }
            } else if (n.equals("B")) {
                x = entrada.nextInt();
                if (x <= lista.size()) {
                    lista.remove(lista.size() - x );
                }
            } else if (n.equals("M")) {
                for (i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.print(lista.get(i));
                }
            } else if (n.equals("F")) {
                break;
            } else {
                m = Integer.parseInt(n);
                lista.add(m);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: y que te esta devolviendo?

Comment: una sola linea con 986986321

Comment: no pareceria ser una linea incorrecta. Primero porque en ningun lado estas agregando un enter (o una linea nueva) para que imprima abajo. Y segundo, porque nunca volves a 0 la lista, con lo cual siempre acumulas valores. tal vez en algun momento querias reiniciarlo? si seguis tu codigo (haciendo un trace con tu herramienta favorita) podes ver exactamente que pasa en cada paso.

Comment: La implementación de `C` es incorrecta, deberias eliminar una cantidad `Y` de elementos, pero ni los indices ni la condicion del `for` tienen sentido.

Answer (score 0):

Fijate en la implementacion de la operacion `C`

```
else if (n.equals("C")) {
    y = entrada.nextInt();
    if (y <= lista.size()) {
        for (i = lista.size() - 1; i == y; i--) {
            lista.removeLast();
        }
    }
}
```

Cuesta seguir la intencion de eso, pero deberia eliminar los ultimos `Y` elementos, algo como:

```
else if (n.equals("C")) {
    y = entrada.nextInt();
    if (y <= lista.size()) {
        for(i=0; i < Math.min(y, lista.size()); ++i) {
            lista.removeLast();
        }
    }
}
```